# Clear cache and cookies using VBScript

Tags: cookies, vbscript, hp-uft

Here is the code I want to use to clear browser history and cache. Is it efficient?

```
'Clear Browser Cache
webutil.DeleteCookies
intWaited = 0
WshShell.Run "Rundll32.exe InetCpl.cpl, ClearMyTracksByProcess 255", 1, True  'Delete All
While Dialog("title:=Delete Browsing History").Exist(1) And intWaited < 10
    wait(1)
    intWaited = intWaited + 1
Wend
intWaited = 0
SystemUtil.Run "RunDll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351"
While Dialog("title:=Delete Browsing History").Exist(1) And intWaited < 10
    wait(1)
    intWaited = intWaited + 1
Wend
```

Comment: Please, post the entire code, including functions declaration and variables initialization.

Comment: The code doesn't look like plain VBScript. Is this UFT? Also, questions about improving working code are better asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yep - that'll be UFT.  Giveaway is `SystemUtil.Run` call

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`Browser.DeleteCookies`](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/Web/WEBPACKAGELib~Browser.html#DeleteCookies) and [`Browser.ClearCache`](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Web/WEBPACKAGELib~Browser.html#ClearCache) methods.

Comment: When running Edge in IE Mode, that causes a "General run error"

Comment: Hi @Zaxxon, I've just checked and (perhaps surprisingly) `DeleteCookies` and `ClearCache` are still supported on Edge IE Mode. Are you sure the IE add-on is enabled?

Comment: I have tried. UFT invoked the Edge browser with an url that goes straight to IE Mode, When the first action is executed, IE Mode is up and running, waiting for login credentials. I tried `Browser("micClass:=Browser").ClearCache` as the first code line, and I get "Run Error: *General run error*" on that line. Skipping to DeleteCookies does the same for that line. RunDll32 does take care of the IE cache, but not Edge Cache.

Comment: You should open a service request with UFT's support.